# bootstrap modal dims everything on the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, bootstrap-modal

From the official [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). I tried the following code but it dims all the page including the modal...

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you modify your css. check your css or your theme that you used.

Comment: in the template itself it worked perfectly but not after I integrated it in YII2.

Comment: check your template css. maybe it conflict the css in yii2